# String function to grab specified character

Tags: php, string

I am searching for a string function which will grab 43 or specified character from a long string character. Suppose: `$char = “this is string and its more than 43 character and function will grab only 43 characters from first”`

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php). This will allow you to select any number of characters from a given offset from a source string.

```
$char = 'this is string and its more than 43 character and function will grab only 43 characters from first';
$num_chars = 43;
$string = substr($char, 0, $num_chars);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```
<?php
$char = substr($char, 0, 43); // strip the value to 43 in length and store in the same variable, where 43 is the desired length
?>
```